# Convenient CBT Questionnaires

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cbt

I have recently done CBT and I am finding a lot of value in the ABCD detective method for myself
https://www.cci.health.wa.gov.au/-/media/CCI/Consumer-Modules/Back-from-The-Bluez/Back-from-the-Bluez---06---Detective-Work-and-Disputation.pdf

ABCD is not the only questionnaire or data collection method that is useful for CBT, but I only seem to find these forms in pdf format, which is not very convenient to fill in and doing the calculations for multiple choice scoring forms at the end seems fully automatable.

I was wondering if there are any recommended websites or apps that provide a service, where these forms are convenient to fill in and does automatic score calculation?